# Using VB Script, how do I automate the creation of an Excel file containing a list of files from a specific folder?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have searched the web but cannot find a specific answer to the following.

What I do know: (1) a txt file of a list of files in S:\Rally can be created from cmd at the S:\Rally prompt:

```
dir/b>H:\Home\list1.txt
```

(2) A new Excel file can be opened by saving the following as .vbs:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

objExcel.Workbooks.Add
```

Then run it in cmd (say the .vbs file is saved as C:\Scripts\openex1.vbs):

```
cscript C:\Scripts\openex1.vbs
```

What I don't know is (1) how to put these together so that an Excel file (instead of a txt file) is created with the resulting list of files from S:\Rally and (2) how to automate this, preferably to run at the end of each month, but I would be fine to just double click something or go into cmd and run it myself at the end of each month.

Answer (score 1):

Would a csv file suit your purpose?  To get a list of files in S:\Rally, you could save a batch file in S:\Rally with one line in it:

```
dir /b > myCsv.csv
```

That would open in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) how to put these together so that an Excel file (instead of a txt
>   file) is created with the resulting list of files from S:\Rally

This is a script that will copy standard input into a blank Excel file and save it using the first argument as a filename.

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
xldata = Split(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
Set a1 = xl.Evaluate("Sheet1!A1")
For i = 0 To UBound(xldata)
    a1.Offset(i).Value = xldata(i)
Next
wb.SaveAs WScript.Arguments(0)
xl.Quit
```

So to run it, save it as `xldump.vbs` and use this command line, piping the output of the `dir /b` into the script.

```
dir /b S:\Rally | cscript xldump.vbs file-list.xlsx
```

> (2) how to automate this, preferably to run at the end of each month,
>   but I would be fine to just double click something or go into cmd and
>   run it myself at the end of each month.

Put the previous command in a batch file and use the Task Scheduler in the Administrative Tools control panel to run it.

Comment: Thanks.  However, this gives the error: 4,1 Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Active X component can't create object

Comment: You can't run this script by double clicking on it because it uses WScript.StdIn. Use the dir /b .... command line from my post.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.  I did use your command line in cmd.  Excel does come up but it is completely blank.  Then cmd gives the aforementioned error.

Comment: Damn, it works perfectly.  I guess the problem was stemming from account permissions or something because when I switched from work computer where I have limited permissions to home computer where I have admin it then works.  Uncertain about this because I do have write rights to the folders in question.  Either way, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hmm, you might be using 32-bit office on a 64-bit OS on your work computer. Try changing the cscript to C:\Windows\SysWow64\cscript to use the 32-bit VBScript.